# Problem configuring mongo db to start up using launch agent

Tags: launchd

After installing mongodb using homebrew, and following the information that homebrew provided, I did the following:

```
launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/org.mongodb.mongod.plist
```

But got the following error:

```
Bug: launchctl.c:2406 (25182):13: (dbfd = open(g_job_overrides_db_path, O_RDONLY | O_EXLOCK | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR)) != -1 
launch_msg(): Socket is not connected
```

Mongodb starts fine in a terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the problem was tmux. When executing launchctl without tmux running this bug doesn't occur.